# Parse file name from URL before downloading the file

Tags: android, download

I'm downloading an ePub file from a URL.

Now I want to implement a mechanism by which if user tries to re-download the same file, he should get warning/error message and that file **should not be** downloaded again.

To implement this, I need to check the name of the file present in my library with the name of the file user is trying to download.

But I just have [this download link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1177388/flagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub), and not the file name.

How to get the name of the file before download in order to compare it with the existing file?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In android you can use [the guessFileName() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#guessFileName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null)
```

Alternatively, a ***simplistic solution*** in Java could be:

```
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

(Assuming your url is in the format: `http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/filename.ext`)

**UPDATE March 23, 2018**

This question is getting lots of hits and someone commented my 'simple' solution does not work with certain urls so I felt the need to improve the answer.

In case you want to handle more complex url pattern, I provided a sample solution below. It gets pretty complex quite quickly and I'm pretty sure there are some odd cases my solution still can't handle but nevertheless here it goes:

```
public static String getFileNameFromURL(String url) {
    if (url == null) {
        return "";
    }
    try {
        URL resource = new URL(url);
        String host = resource.getHost();
        if (host.length() > 0 && url.endsWith(host)) {
            // handle ...example.com
            return "";
        }
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        return "";  
    }

    int startIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    int length = url.length();

    // find end index for ?
    int lastQMPos = url.lastIndexOf('?');
    if (lastQMPos == -1) {
        lastQMPos = length; 
    }

    // find end index for #
    int lastHashPos = url.lastIndexOf('#');
    if (lastHashPos == -1) {
        lastHashPos = length;   
    }

    // calculate the end index
    int endIndex = Math.min(lastQMPos, lastHashPos);
    return url.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```

This method can handle these type of input:

```
Input: "null" Output: ""
Input: "" Output: ""
Input: "file:///home/user/test.html" Output: "test.html"
Input: "file:///home/user/test.html?id=902" Output: "test.html"
Input: "file:///home/user/test.html#footer" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com" Output: ""
Input: "http://www.example.com" Output: ""
Input: "http://www.example.txt" Output: ""
Input: "http://example.com/" Output: ""
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html?param=value" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html#anchor" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html#anchor?param=value" Output: "test.html"
```

You can find the whole source code here: https://ideone.com/uFWxTL

Comment: suppose I have a link which contains collection of books(for eg. `www.bookstore.com`),  from which I select one book(with URL `www.bookstore.com/book1.epub`) which should be downloaded to my library. **How will I get the URL of specific book** i.e. `www.bookstore.com/book1.epub` ??? `webView.getUrl()` doesn't get fired at all except for first load.

Comment: Your solution works only if there neither params (?param=value) nor anchor (#anchor).

Comment: really appreciate it for your answer, it helps a lot

Answer (score 51):

Try to use `URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null)` for example. I think this is the best Android way.

More info here: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#guessFileName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#guessFileName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 9):

Keep it simple :

```
/**
 * This function will take an URL as input and return the file name.
 * <p>Examples :</p>
 * <ul>
 * <li>http://example.com/a/b/c/test.txt -> test.txt</li>
 * <li>http://example.com/ -> an empty string </li>
 * <li>http://example.com/test.txt?param=value -> test.txt</li>
 * <li>http://example.com/test.txt#anchor -> test.txt</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @param url The input URL
 * @return The URL file name
 */
public static String getFileNameFromUrl(URL url) {

    String urlString = url.getFile();

    return urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).split("\\?")[0].split("#")[0];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think using URL#getPath() should simplify things.

```
public static String getFileNameFromUrl(URL url) {

    String urlPath = url.getPath();

    return urlPath.substring(urlPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}
```

See, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#getPath()

Comment: I use it but not because simplify things, with getPath() you can handle url that have query parameters like httt://domain.com/file.ext?a=1#anchor as @TimAutin do but more readable for me.

Answer (score 2):

You dont really have to compare file names. Just make **File** object for the file with absolute path and check if file exists.

```
protected boolean need2Download(String fileName) {

    File basePath = new File(BOOK_STORE_PATH);

    File fullPath = new File(basePath, fileName);

    if (fullPath.exists())
        return false;
    return true;
}

protected void downloadFile(String url) {
    String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if (need2Download(fileName)) {
        // download
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get file name from `FilenameUtils` from `apache commons-io`

```
URL url = URL(fileUrl)
String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(url.getPath())
```

To this add `commons-io` dependency in build.gradle(app)

```
implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.6"
```

It also extracts the file name from the complex URL like below

`http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/file.xml?foo=bar#test`