# How to download files from Android default download manager with actual file name?

Tags: android, mysql

I've made an Android Application that can download mp3 songs when clicked on the ListView of songs. I've used this

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"MySong.mp3");
```

But my songs are updated from time to time from mysql database. When I use the above method, all the songs are downloaded with the file name of **MySong.mp3**

If I avoid the above method, the file downloads with actual file name but it is deleted as soon as the download completes. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575943/parse-file-name-from-url-before-downloading-the-file

Comment: Following the way you did, whenever you donwload new song it will rename it as `MySong.mp3` and as the previous one has also the same name, it will overwrite it. So you have to come up with a method to generate a unique name for each song. Ex: you can append `id` to the end of the song name. Be sure that you always check firstly if that name already exist in the folder so you generate another name. That way you will avoid ovewriting songs

Answer (score 0):

so.. this is how I'm doing it, I believe this should help you.

```
//define the path of your file location.
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                +File.separator + "FOLDER_NAME" + File.separator + fileName;

//create the new file.
final File saveFile = new File(path);

//make all the directory structures needed if the location doesn't exist.
File parentDest = saveFile.getParentFile();
        if (!parentDest.exists()) {
            parentDest.mkdirs(); 
        }
```

after setting this up you have to make sure you are giving the DownloadManager the exact path for this file.

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    File.separator + "FOLDER_NAME" + File.separator + fileName);
```

hope this helps,
JozeRi

Comment: The problem is not with the download location sir, the actual problem is with the file name that is being downloaded

Comment: how do you get the song? can't you fetch the song name somewhere so you could give it the correct name then?

Comment: The link and mp3 files change every time I update them in my database. Anyways found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the link provided in the comment I've followed this and it worked. Thanks for the link @CommonsWare

```
String url = "www.somedownloalink.com/some-song.mp3";

String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,filename);
```

Comment: can do this way too `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"MySong"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp3");`