# How to know name of the file before downloading it?

Tags: android

I was thinking of the `guessFileName()` method as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576046/8564420).

But this requires you to know the URL. Is there any other way?

Comment: How would you download the file if you don't know the url?

Comment: I was thinking if the file was being downloaded by another app like chrome or reddit gifs etc.