# Android download file and name it as it is in server using retrofit

Tags: java, android, file, retrofit

I have an api that returns a pdf file. When I place the url in browser I'm getting the file with some specified name -Not fixed- and it's based on the query sent in the url.

However when I download this file from my app , I had to name the file myself I don't want that
I want the same name the file was originally named in the server.

How can I achieve this?

Retrofit request

```
private void initDownload(){

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://../.../API/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
    
    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> request = retrofitInterface.downloadClientFile(8685);
    try {
        downloadFile(request.execute().body());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here where I got the body and then create file with name

```
private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {

    int count;
    byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
    long fileSize = body.contentLength();
    InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(body.byteStream(), 1024 * 8);
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "file.pdf");
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
     // Rest of the code ...
}
```

In API implementation , The file name is returned in the response header as below

```
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName
```

Comment: If url contains file name then look at   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575943/parse-file-name-from-url-before-downloading-the-file.  Does your response contains file name ? Or you are just getting the contents of the file ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA I checked the implementation of the API. the response header contains the file name but I don't know how to read it. I have updated my question

Answer (score -1):

To get the file name in Header section of Response, you can try :

```
    val response = request.execute()
    val headers = response.headers().names()
    headers.forEach {
        Log.d(TAG,"$it")
    }
   val responseBody = response.body()
```

Comment: Yes but if you check my code I'm not using asynchronous call with overriding success and failure. I have a ResponseBody not Response

Comment: Okay, can you please try with my updated answer. Let me know your result, please.

Comment: I tried it , this is what I got in log in each iteration cache-control,
content-length.
date,
pragma..
x-aspnet-version

Comment: `response.headers().names()` gives a list of header names. This doesn't show the filename that was set on the response.